# How can I migrate from Selenium IDE to Selenium2/ Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Before I always used just Selenium IDE and now should migrate to Selenium2/Selenium WebDriver. What should I install and know to use Selenium2/Selenium WebDriver. Should I know any programming language?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium 2 supports many different programming languages.  The language you'll get he most out of selenium is Java, but c# and python drivers are maintained by the community.  Personally I use python, and find some gaps from the original java version but have been very succesfuly thus far.  If you do not know any programming languages, and/or anything about designing, the project you are working on may not be as successful as you may think and you will be spending most of your time refactoring/maintaining things all the time.  You should really know what expectations are set for the project

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this Blog Post helps you:

- http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/03/moving-to-selenium-2-on-webdriver-part.html
- http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/03/moving-to-selenium-2-on-webdriver-part_26.html
- http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/04/moving-to-selenium-2-on-webdriver-part.html